# Visual Studio 2010 takes too long loading symbols, symbol file location cannot be removed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols

Visual Studio takes a lot of extra time loading symbols for external dlls which I'd rather not load. I have fiddled with my symbol settings in VS2008 and these settings seem to be affecting VS2010

How do I stop it loading 3rd party symbols?
I've tried:

- devenv /resetuserdata
- Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols (I can't remove or uncheck the pdb file location of: "Environment Variable: _NT_SYMBOL_PATH")
- I've cleared the above location like so: set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH=
  actually this made a huge difference (it was previously SRV*c:\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols)
- I've deleted everything from: %localappdata%\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\

The next thing would be a VS re-install, failing that an OS re-install, but if it saves me 14 seconds every time I press debug it would be worth it.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer? This just started happening to me and it's  annoying.

Comment: I thought I should add a note to say; I never figured this out, but since I've reinstalled, upgraded, etc the problem is gone (mostly).

Answer (score 46):

Try [Debug -> Delete All Breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3759864)

Comment: This was a surprise, thanks for posting - solved the same issue for me.

Comment: I don't believe this. IT WORKED!!! I even bougth a new computer to get rid if this!! Of course it didn't work, just improved a little. THANKS DUDE!!! can i vote many many times???

Comment: Clearing breakpoints worked for me too. I found this link first (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsdebug/thread/98f50717-c842-4bb1-8676-f64d453f80d1).

Comment: I was taking 5 minutes to launch a web app from visual studio - this solved it. +1

Comment: Simple and very effective. Works.

Comment: My solution got a big .xml file to process. I can reproduce this slow issue by putting a breakpoint in that file. Get ride that breakpoint and it get back to the trails (why a breakpoint in a xml file?)

Answer (score 21):

Things to try

- Tools > Options Debugging > General

  - [Disable source server support](http://saraford.net/2008/08/15/did-you-know-why-you-may-want-to-enable-source-server-support-292/)
  - [Enable just my code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e30exc.aspx)(just tested and greatly improved load times for me) -[when to disable](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/10/03/releasing-the-source-code-for-the-net-framework-libraries.aspx)
  - Disable .NET framework source stepping (automatically disables just my code if selected)
- Tools > Options>Debugging > [Symbols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x54fht41.aspx)

  - Only Specified Modules
  - Or All modules unless excluded and exclude those 3rd party
  - I was able to remove all checks under .pdb locations, but I had `d:\refsrc\symbols` as an added location

Comment: referencesource.microsoft.com is offline - therefore symbols cannot be loaded and it takes forever...

Comment: This is a better solution than disabling breakpoints all the time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble too.  I did not think that I had set _NT_SYMBOL_PATH but somehow it was set  to the path I use when using WinDbg.  I figured this out by running ProcMon from the SysInternals Suite and filtered out everything except DevEnv.exe and saw what files it was trying to access when debugging my application.

I deleted the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH environmental, restarted VS and everything runs like it should.

I offer this not so much for the answer which was supplied in the initial question but as guidance on how to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had previously turned on Debugging -> Symbols -> All modules and forgot to turn it off when I was done with a particular project.  Turning off this setting greatly improved my load times.

Answer (score 0):

I had this trouble too. And I fix it easily. Just do: **Debug->Options and Settings->Symbols. In Symbols I checked Only Specified Modules**. Everything works fine again. Hope this helps.