# Breakpoints go hollow when application is debugged...?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-xp, chromium

I'm trying to debug a project in VS2008.  I can place breakpoints in the code, but as soon as I start debugging, the breakpoints go hollow.  Mousing over the hollow points I get the message "the breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version."

I've tried both cleaning & rebuilding the project and rebooting the machine.  I've still got the problem.

Any ideas?

Also, Visual Studio and the project (Chromium) are on a different partition from the system files (Windows XP).  Does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, make sure that the source file you have opened is REALLY REALLY the file that was compiled (you may have several repositories of Chromium on your disk.) To be really sure, close the tab and open it from the Solution Explorer (not using `Ctrl-O` and manually finding the file in your file system.)

If that is not the case, this may be a manifestation of a well-known MSVS issue where it thinks that the built DLLs and the respective PDBs (debug symbol files) have different versions (essentially, UIDs embedded during the build.) Try manually removing the output directory (`chromium/src/build/Debug` in your case) and see if it helps.

Also see the ["The breakpoint will not currently be hit. The source code is different from the original version." What does this mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468852/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-the-source-code-is-different-from-the) question for possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  In the end I gave up on trying to build chromium, so I can't confirm that any of these suggestions would have solved my problem.  Nonetheless, they sound well thought out and I appreciate that you took the time to write them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the acceptance, dB'! I'm actually a Chrome developer, so feel free to ask more questions if you definitely need to build it :)