# in VS 2005 what does it mean when breakpoints are not hit when debugging a Debug build?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

If I go to Configuration Manager and set the Configuration field to "Debug" and hit F5, the breakpoints are not hit. (these are breakpoints in the first line of the Main() method).

If I set the Configuration field to "Release" and run the app the breakpoints are hit.

I also noticed that when I run the Debug build, the breakpoints are hit only if I select Target x86 or x64, but not when I select ANY CPU.

What is the cause of this behavior?

Comment: Did you make a fresh build before? Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468852/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-the-source-code-is-different-from-the?rq=1 and tried what was suggested there?

Comment: make sure that Configuration Manager options in your solution are set to build your projects in Debug

Comment: Doc Brown, I did read the answers to that question and none of the solutions seem to work. It's interesting that I have this problem ONLY when I'm working with a Debug build of a particular application.

Comment: Paul Farry, I made sure of that

Comment: When `Optimize Code` is on, some information stored in the debug file (pdb) is not accurate anymore. By default this is on when you set your build to `Release` mode.

Comment: When you start debugging, what does the breakpoint look like?  Is it a hollow circle with a yellow mark?  This would mean it isn't able to match the symbols(.PDB) to your current process.

Comment: Silvermind, I made sure that all configurations have Optimize Code off and still have the same problem. taylorjonl, that's exactly what I see the moment I hit F5. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Ah, the "symbols have not been loaded." :) Provided that your configuration manager options are set up properly for the build, what generally fixes this issue for me is to do a full solution clean, then in Explorer, completely wipe all /bin and /obj folders from the solution then doing a rebuild. I've seen this issue most commonly on things like web projects or customized /bin output setups. What seems to happen is VS doesn't detect that a project needs to be rebuilt/copied and does not overwrite an assembly in one of the output folders. (leaving an incorrect one, gumming the works.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem :)

```
   Solution Explorer ->
   Right click on the solution ->
   Properties ->
   Build ->
   Advanced button ->
   Debug Info: <change from none to pdb-only>
```