# No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line - mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

Receiving the following error:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No executable code of the debugger's target code type is associated with this line.  Possible causes include: conditional compilation, compiler optimizations, or the target architecture of this line is not supported by the current debugger code type.

The same error happens on any MVC project, even if I create a brand new project for testing this issue.  The error is when I set a breakpoint on any javascript line in my .cshtml files.  For example, I receive this error if I set a breakpoint on "alert" below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('test');
</script>
```

**Environment**: Windows 7 64bit, VS2017 15.8.8, Framework 4.6.1, MVC Empty application.
Create one controller and one view, add this code to the bottom of the view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('test');
</script>
```

Then I receive the error when I start debugging, the error shows on the breakpoint circle for that line.

**Settings**: (All default settings, nothing has been modified)

- Define DEBUG Constant is checked
- Define TRACE Constant is checked
- Advanced-Debugging information is full

I have tried rebooting the machine with no help.  Everything was working fine a couple of days ago.

**Update**: (Here is a picture of debug settings)

[image]

Comment: Check [this setting](https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/11/debugger-settings-1024x690.png)

Comment: Stuart, thanks for your help!  It looks like it was set that way, please take a look at the update.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2155930/how-do-i-remedy-the-the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-no-symbols-have-b and also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2468852/the-breakpoint-will-not-currently-be-hit-the-source-code-is-different-from-the.

Comment: Rui, I saw those links. However those are for a different error.  I did try those suggestions in any case but they did not help.  Thank you.

Comment: Any update I am facing issue same issue.