# Source mismatch in Debug after Build when main app loads dll dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild

I'm wondering if somebody had a same issue with project building:
So, I have a solution where I have one main project and second project with is not referenced directly by main app

mianApp.csproj
plugin.csproj

during a build process I'm building mainApp to 'publish' direcotry  and plugin.dll is copied by post build event to 'publish\plugins'. When application starts loads plugin.dll dynamically.

The main problem is that when I change something in plugin.csproj always need to Rebuild whole solution, when I'm running app in Debug after Build, I'm always getting information that my source file was changed and any breakpoint cannot be hit.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Kindly check if this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25879968/16363677) helps. I think VS may be using an old copy somewhere. Besides, try to delete the `.vs`, `bin` and `obj` and other related cache folders and then have a try.

Comment: Is your issue solved?